# Alignment of bullet points in Modern CV

Tags: moderncv, cv

**Question**: How do I align the bullet points in a CV, using the `Modern CV` package? I would like to the statistics and economics bullet points under the 'Economics and Statistics Tutor' heading.

Current looks like the following:

[image]

MWE:

```
% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}                  % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)
%\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                % idem

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                     % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\maketitlenamewidth}{6cm}}  % only for the classic theme, if you want to change the width of your name placeholder (to leave more space for your address details
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}                     % required when changes are made to page layout lengths
\usepackage{enumitem}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\nopagenumbers{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Experience}
\cventry{Jan 2015 - Present}{Researcher}{Development Policy Research Unit}{University of Cape Town}{} {} {} {}
\vspace{1.0\baselineskip}

\cventry{Jun 2014 - July 2014}{Intern}{Economic Research Southern Africa}{Claremont}{}{Provided assistance on data compilation and cleaning. \newline{}Provided assistance on data analysis. \newline{}Provided assistance on literature searches.} 
\vspace{1.0\baselineskip}
\cventry{Jul 2013 - Nov 2013}{Research Assistant}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{Provided assistance regarding the literature review portion of the \newline{} WHO Alcohol Study report.}

\cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Economics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item{\textbf{Statistics}:} Prepared tutorials, marked tests and projects and participating in computer lab sessions.
\item{\textbf{Economics}}: Ensured timely upload of documents and other administrative duties.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \moderncvtheme`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the list in the entry rather than after it:

```
\cventry{Feb 2012 - Nov 2014}{Economics and Statistics Tutor}{University of Cape Town}{Cape Town}{}{
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item{\textbf{Statistics}:} Prepared tutorials, marked tests and projects and participating in computer lab sessions.
\item{\textbf{Economics}}: Ensured timely upload of documents and other administrative duties.
\end{itemize}}
```

It also helps if you add

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
```